# Can I use JOSE for Signed and Encrypted API Request and Response for Server to Server API communication?

Tags: spring, api, security, jwt, jose

As the documentation says:

> JOSE [1](https://jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a framework intended to provide a method to securely
> transfer claims (such as authorization information) between parties.
> [Doc](https://jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Is JOSE is only used for **Authentication and Authorization** activities or can it be used while **"Data in transit"** to secure sensitive data (along with SSL and TLS)? As this Hyperwallet example below describes payload encryption: [API DOC](https://docs.hyperwallet.com/content/api/v3/overview/payload-encryption)

Can I use JOSE for Signed and Encrypted API Request and Response beside Authentication for Server to Server Communication Scenario to secure sensitive data?

Comment: it's basically a collection of technical specifications of the token formats and algorithms used to sign and encrypt. What would stop you to use it for your purposes? If I understand it correctly, you link to an example in which JOSE is used for a non authentication/authorization use case. So the answer is: yes, you can.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Can you give some examples for Spring boot REST API implementation? It will be very helpful.

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid You can check this if you wish.